# Does AddressSanitizer use a different standard library? (C programming)

Tags: clang, address-sanitizer

Do you guys know why the AddressSanitizer would be taking a whole different set of libraries.

For instance, I was trying to recreate strcmp, when I was comparing my output with the standard strcmp from string.h but what I realized is that compiling it normally with gcc it outputs the difference, but with the -fsanitize=address flag added it gives me 1, 0, -1 outputs.

both gcc and clang behave the same way

I am on a OSX 10.11.6, btw.
Is this behavior unique to MACOS or other systems have similar effects?

Btw, from what I was reading, the strcmp of the GNU C library outputs the difference and the Apple version only has outputs of 1, -1 and 0.
So this is even more puzzling to me, because the gcc/clang in MACOS seems to be using the gnu libc by default, and somehow shifting to the apple's version of libc when using the -fsanitize=address flag.

If anyone can explain this to me I would very grateful.
btw, just in case, this is my configuration of gcc:

```
➜ gcc --version
Configured with:
--prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
    Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: The reason `gcc` and `clang` behave the same way on macOS Sierra (and Mac OS X) is that they're the same program.  Run `gcc --version` and `clang --version` and you'll see.  And the program is based on Clang rather than GCC.  You may find running with `gcc -v` (or `clang -v`) and with or without the `-fsanitize=address` option shows what's going.  I don't know why different libraries are used.  Any code that depends on the magnitudes of what `strcmp()` returns is ultimately broken — you shouldn't care whether it returns -1 or -90 for a difference.

Comment: I understand that, but my worry is, if -sanitize=address is actually switching libraries, as clearly seems to be doing, what else is it gonna be changing.

Answer (score 1):

`-fsanitize=address` forces your binary to link against Asan runtime which overloads a lot of standard functions (including [strcmp](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/ca23873aed881901a967372e61ee64634d634970/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc#L271)). Overloading is done to check input arguments to these functions. Asan implementations are generally standard-compliant but don't follow all the nits for a particular platform so this may be the reason for differences that you see.